# fully-loaded baked potato with Gummy Bears

Tags: meaning

> "...you probably don’t want to see three different photos of steak, no
>   matter how well composed those shots are. You’ll also want to see a
>   photo of the fully-loaded baked potato with Gummy Bears on it, and the
>   mechanical bull out front..."
>
> [wired.com](http://www.wired.com/2015/10/yelp-is-teaching-its-computers-to-see-places-at-their-best/)

What does "fully loaded" mean? 
And why is potato served with gummy bears? Is that some kind of a joke?

Comment: I'm guessing: "if you're marketing a restaurant, use photos of the unusual dishes you offer, not the ones available at a million other establishments. Be distinctive."  *Fully-loaded* here means "with all the accompaniments" and other available ingredients.

Comment: Sure, sometimes a baked potato may have gummy bears added as a final touch.

Comment: A "fully loaded" baked potato has been split open and filled with ground beef, vegetables, sour cream, etc.  Adding Gummy Bears would be a bit over-the-top and silly, which is why it would make an interesting picture.

Comment: I think it is a typo.  The preceding sentence says "you don't want..." But is followed by "you'll also want..." which doesn't make sense.  I think it should be "You also won't want to see..."

Comment: @michael_timofeev - I think it's correct (though a hair awkward) as it stands -- no typo.  The point is that people don't want to see pictures of things they've seen before and which are in no way unique -- those don't draw customer attention.

Comment: @HotLicks. You could be right.  It's bad writing, anyway because two intelligent people like us are debating it.  Fine for poetry or jamesjoyce but a simple article...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fully-loaded* in this sense means "with all the available toppings" (synonymous with *with everything* as in "a large pizza with everything"). Marketing language often defies grammar and/or sensibilities. In this case, however, I ***strongly*** advise you to eat at another restaurant.

Comment: What?  And miss out on the Gummy Bears?